# What is considered 'vampirism' of an answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, plagiarism

I recently answered a question where another user and I had almost identical answers, and they added more to theirs as time went on. I then did a gigantic edit which encompassed all their other edits and added considerably more explanation.

As a consequence of the huge edit, I got the checkmark, but all was not well. The other user seemed to think I had committed 'vampirism' of their answer due to my edit, costing them the checkmark. I believe my answer was more in depth in explanation, but I did gain from the edits done to their answer.

My question is: is this considered 'vamipirism' of answer, as in stealing content? I felt like my edit explained a lot more, and many parts were added for completeness of the answer. Is this frowned upon - editing parts of your answer to encompass other's answers? Would this be considered plagiarism?

Update: I have removed a large portion of the answer, not for concealing alleged plagiarism, but for relevancy. After reviewing, I didn't feel like that portion was relevant to the answer.

Comment: Note: I've refrained from mentioning the post as to keep the user anonymous. By request, I will give proper links and context if needed, but I'd rather not if at all possible.

Comment: Hard to guess what "vampirism" might mean, it sounds like he meant plagiarism.  Perhaps not entirely unjustified, but hard to make the call.  You'll have to keep in mind that he'll remember and probably is never going to upvote one of your posts again.  Y'all have to learn how to get along :)  Given that his post was so helpful to assist you in writing a much better answer, did you upvote it?  Then you can simply comment: "Sorry, I did not mean to create the impression that I plagiarized your work.  Thank you, you helped me write a better answer and I've upvoted your post".

Comment: @HansPassant I was in the process of adding a huge addition to the answer, and I decided to add more explanation to parts of their answer for completeness. I felt like it would benefit future readers so I took that move, and yes, I did upvote it.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm not that kind of user, who downvotes on emotion. I downvote on obviously incorrect answers (or bad questions), which OP's answer was not.

Comment: I don't think anyone else in the history of Stack Overflow has used "vampirism" when talking about answers.

Comment: @BoltClock haha, I explained my definition of _vampirism_ in this case in my answer, but yeah, it might sound weird as I'm not a native English speaker.

Comment: In this context, [vampire usually refers to something else](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/) - *help vampire* or just *vampire*.

Comment: @PeterMortensen I am aware of help vampire, the concept of vampire here still applies since it's about feeding from someone else. It be to be helped, or to construct your own answer, there's feeding going on.

Comment: I think the big issue is there is too much concern about points and gaining the coveted "selected answer" checkbox, when instead the idea is to provide help to someone. Ignore the points earned and instead fill in missing holes in their knowledge and the points will follow eventually. Copying content from one answer to another doesn't help, it only duplicates the information needlessly. Remember, points and reputation don't buy you anything except more responsibility and the expectation you'll find additional ways to help the community.

Comment: @theTinMan While I agree that in a perfect world nobody would care about the reputation, each has his motivation and it would be lying to ourselves to say that reputation isn't one. It drives most people to answer as it quantify their effort on the site. After the first 25k, the incentive to earn rep is almost gone and rep just goes up anyway with the accumulated questions and answers backlog.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd personally want to see it to identify the context, but...it's not outside of the realm of possibility that two people can arrive at identical answers at or near the same time.

While this may be in a gray area for most, since it eliminates the benefit of the doubt...

> ... I then did a gigantic edit which **encompassed all their other edits**

...the fact that you added more explanation in your own words and phrasing improves the answers received, and allowed the OP to consider one clearly.

I'd take a harder stance on a plagiarized answer if you had blatantly copied their work verbatim without doing anything additional, and tried to pass it off as your own - this includes not adding a citation to work that you had built off of.  It happens more than you realize.

Whether or not the other answerer thinks that you "stole" their answer is another matter; two answers can be correct, but one can always be *better* than another.

---

Since I've been able to find the original post and I've had a look at both [the OP's original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/40581550/1) and [the accuser's original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/40581535/1), I'm sticking by my original assertion that this *initial* work doesn't feel like plagiarism.  It's within the time of variance that two answerers could have similar-looking answers within the same amount of time (and honestly, they're not *that* similar looking).

The colossal edit since adds documentation from the language spec, which reinforces existing knowledge and adds a verifiable reference, which I take to be *better* than even strong inferential evidence; this is what the language is **specified** to do, and having that illustrated for an asker is only a good thing.

One could get really pedantic and argue that [precedence *was* mentioned **before**](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/40581535/3) it appeared in the [massive edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/40581550/2), which is where it gets dodgy.

Under normal pretenses, I wouldn't see it rising to the occasion of plagiarism, since the knowledge in contention concerns a commonly known fact about parentheses and order-of-operations.  However, since you [do admit to looking at that answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337817/what-is-considered-vampirism-of-an-answer#comment412044_337817), which is a fact that I did skim over, you owe the original creator some form of attribution, or it *would* be considered plagiarism.

Comment: I was once accused of "stealing" an answer on another question. The questions were pretty much the same and not just the content but also the wording of the answers were indeed very similar. Luckily I was able to prove my innocence by pointing out that I had posted my answer almost a year before his :-) Point is: for a comparatively simple question there is often just one (or at most a few) possible answers, and even if we say there are 500 ways to word that, then these sort of "duplicate" answers happen fairly often simply due to the sheer number of answers that are posted.

Comment: If you paraphrase someone else's work into your own words *it is still their original work, and you need to cite it as such when using it*.  Re-phrasing someone else's content does not suddenly allow you to claim that as your own original work.  Now, if the person arrived as a similar solution *independantly*, then sure, that's fine.  But it doesn't sound like he did.  He implied that he read through the other user's answers and incorporated that content into his own.  Doing so without citing the other's work *is plagiarism*.

Comment: @Servy:  You're absolutely right, but I did get a chance to look at the edit histories of both answers.  I'm not seeing it rise to that occasion *necessarily*, although there's a decent amount of gray area that one could argue here.

Comment: @Makoto The author pretty clearly *admitted* that he looked at the other user's answer and incorporated content from that answer into his own.  If he didn't say as much, then perhaps you're right that there isn't sufficient evidence to suggest that he didn't independantly create similar content, but *we don't have to guess; he told us what he did*.

Comment: Also note that multiple small edits were really close in time, by the same user (OP), so they were merged into what seems to be the original answer but is not what actually happened chronologically.

Comment: @Servy:  The way I read it is that the massive edit happened after both parties had answered.  The initial "benefit of the doubt" period happens when the initial answers hit.  After the edit is when more work has to be done to satisfy the contentious issue of a user plagiarizing someone else's work, and even after that, the OP added attribution to their answer because it *was* mentioned earlier.

Comment: @EmileBergeron:  I'm only capable of looking at the edit history.   What is shown there is all we can realistically go off of, and yes there is a grace period that exists for edits that can miss rapid changes to a post.  However, in your answer, the portion concerning adding parentheses wasn't even added by you, but in all fairness, it was still incorporated into the answer.

Comment: Attribution was added tens of hours later, by request. I agree that it's not worth doing anything about it. I did not began this, OP did.

Comment: @EmileBergeron:  You *did* accuse them of being a vampire.  It isn't polite, and plagiarism is something we take *seriously* on this site.  The OP wanted to be sure that they were acting with the best intentions and weren't blatantly plagiarizing anything.  You may have felt robbed or cheated that you didn't get the acceptance mark, but when I look at these two answers *today*, I still would feel like the answer with more reference material would deserve being accepted.

Comment: Yes, today it is, because I did not wanted to be the guy who competition for the upvotes. And since I called him out on it, he made everything possible for his answer to be top notch before being scrutinized by everyone. I did not really accused him impolitely, I said that it **looks** more like vampirism to me. Which I still think it is, and [Danra](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/337856/1218980) make a great point on what he should have done instead.

Comment: @Makoto Considering you've posted an answer to the question that's saying anything short of copy-pasting someone else's entire post isn't' plagiarism, in response to someone asking if they did anything wrong by using someone else's original content without citing them, you don't seem to be taking it too seriously.  Even if you think the plagiarised work is better, that doesn't make it not plagiarized.

Comment: @Servy:  No, I do take it seriously, I'm simply giving the OP the benefit of the doubt here.  Given that the issue in contention is a fact that can be found in most common JavaScript operator tutorials, it still doesn't register as plagiarism for me, since putting parentheses around statements to force an order of operations is abundant knowledge in programming.  It's not a unique concept or idea to be had on behalf of the accuser.  Don't get me wrong, I genuinely despise plagiarism.  It's just that this concept isn't entirely owned or sourced from the accuser.  I could be wrong, though.

Comment: Also, you posted the wrong version of my answer. The [edit by Evan](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/40581535/2) was made before he posted his last version (within the grace period).

Comment: It's not that he guessed the same answer, it's that he even took the wording and all, the order of the sentences, every edits were added into his immediately after I added more.

Comment: @EmileBergeron:  If you had screenshots to suggest that kind of timeline, that'd help, but again, since I can only see the edit history, that's all any of us can go off of.

Comment: If you check the timestamp, the edit by Evan is before he posted his answer.

Comment: @Makoto Like I said, your answer states that anything that's not a copy-paste isn't plagiarism, and that's just flat wrong.  Regardless of the specific case in question, your answer is unambiguously incorrect in it's statement of what plagiarism is.

Comment: As to the specific answer, *the author specifically admitted that they used another user's content*.  So we *know* that he used another user's original work.  Your argument that he could have created the content independantly, and that it's plausible for two people to independantly create this content is *rendered moot* when he *admits* that he didn't create the content independantly in this instance.

Comment: @Servy:  Okay.  I'll go ahead and revise my answer.  I can see how that can be an issue.

Comment: Note that it's unfair to only look at the original answer of each one as it's also about any subsequent edits made.

Comment: @Servy / Makoto There has been no adjustment to this answer yet to credit EmileBergeron - if that is the desired outcome as discuessed here. I don't want to change the accepted answer, because in X amount of years time, the current answer will still be the most informative.

Comment: @Zze:  [It looks like there has been](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40581550/1079354) for quite some time now, unless I'm missing something here...

Comment: @Makoto ...... To the optometrist I go... Sorry...

Comment: @Zze in fact, the best outcome would be that Andrew makes his answer a community wiki as discussed on [_An elegant solution for “answer-stealing” edits?_](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/21643/254800). It's true that his answer is now more informative, but mostly because my whole answer is part of his. Don't change the accept, initially, I only wanted to make you aware of the situation and nothing more.

Comment: @EmileBergeron I will be more critical in future before accepting answers after substantial edits.

Comment: @Servy To address the concern - I did not explicitly take words from the other answer. My intention was to make an edit with spec info, but then to make the answer more complete I added more info I saw in the other answer. By saw, I do not mean plagiarize, I mean took the idea from it. The other answer offered something about precedence, so I incorporated that into the answer - with more explanation. (Transformative in nature)

Comment: @EmileBergeron Note: I did not take the wording - my first ever answer had 'makes absolutely no sense'. I do admit I took your idea of precedence - *but I transformed it by adding more explanation*. Also, about the solution edit by Evan: I will admit fully that I took that from your answer, but I again transformed it with some explanation. I'm not sure if that's *ethical* and I'm sorry for being unethical - but it's not plagiarism. Someone *else* edited that in your answer.

Comment: @AndrewLi `I do not mean plagiarize, I mean took the idea from it.`  *That is what plagiarism is*.  Plagiarism is taking the ideas of another person and claiming them as your own.  Even if you use your own words *it's still plagiarism* if you're not citing those ideas as being someone else's.  What you've described doing is *the very definition of plagiarism*; it is a textbook, unambiguous case of plagiarism.

Answer (score 13):

Since, as you said, you were incorporating the work of another user into an edit, you need to provide a citation for that in your answer.  Even if you're not using their exact words, but are simply expressing their ideas in your own words, you still need to indicate that in your answer.

Now it *is* common for different people to arrive at the same, or a similar, answer to a problem independantly, and that's okay.  Particularly with very simple problems it's common for multiple people to arrive at the same solution at around the same time.  But since you have said that you incorporated content of another user into later edits, you're saying that at least some of the ideas in your answer are not your own original works.  You have since edited the answer to attribute these ideas to their author, but as you didn't originally the original author of that content was *quite right* to be concerned, and to indicate as much in a comment, because what you did *was* plagiarism.

Answer (score 12):

Disclaimer: *I'm the person who "accused" OP of vampirism. I said in a reply to his defensive comment: "To me, this looks more like vampirism from my answer..." (someone deleted the comment)*

*What happened is hard to tell from the edit history as all the first edits were so close they were merged into one, making it look like his original answer was already complete.*

*Now that this is being discussed in meta and that I called him out on it, he's edited every sentences took from my answer to be in his own words and removed some blatant copy-paste. I did finally upvote his, though it leaves a sour taste in my mouth.*

Despite this situation,

- **I did not downvoted OP**.
- **I did not discredited his additional edit** (quotes from the specs).
- **I did not flagged his answer**.
- **I did not made a meta post about it**.
- **I did not put his *gigantic* edit** into mine to make both equivalent answer.

What I mean by **vampirism** is the behavior of including relevant parts **word for word** of another answer to feed from the early upvotes.

## What happened

OP made an almost identical answer minutes after mine *which was believable being quite simple at first*. It's something that happens often when all the first answers appears in the first minute or two.

And as I edited critical information into mine, seconds later they were word for word edited into his. Then, when mine was complete enough for the asker, OP added a little more which looks like he just tried to steal the accept from the asker.

The asker asked me for clarification, which I added as a comment, then an edit into my answer. These were also edited in OP answer. Then the asker said something like (the comments were all removed):

> Thanks for your time and answer, but as Andrew have gone above and beyond, I accepted his.

Which would be fine if it was a real improvement, but the *gigantic edit which encompassed all my other edits* is just quotes from the specifications. The relevant is word for word from my answer.

## Some examples

03:36, I wrote:

> And **when you try** `b1 = !b2 = true;`, the equivalent **makes no sense**:

03:38, He then wrote:

> **When you try** to do this: ...snip code... that **makes** absolutely **no sense**

03:42, I wrote:

> This is because the **`!` takes [precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) on the `=` assignment operator**.

04:02, He then wrote:

> This is because `!` takes [precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)<sup>†</sup> over `=`

*<strike>Now crediting mine per request.</strike> Now completely removed any references to precedence.*

03:38, Someone included in my answer:

> You can make it work as you expect by adding parentheses:
>
> ```
> b1 = !(b2 = true);
> ```

He then wrote (*this edit looks like it was merged in the initial answer edit but was definetly after the answer was posted, and definetely after mine as I saw it appeared as a single edit*):

> You can combat this by doing:
>
> ```
> b2 = !(b1 = true);
> ```

From my point of view, this has already been discussed, see [An elegant solution for “answer-stealing” edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21643/an-elegant-solution-for-answer-stealing-edits).

Comment: Also, I made a comment before any answer stating 'it made no sense'. I said it was 'obviously wrong'

Comment: @AndrewLi that was 2 minutes after I wrote it. I know it's short and maybe you had the same words in mind, but it looks fishy as hell.

Comment: The comment, no. And 'fishy as hell' isn't proof of malice. If I could, I would let you read my mind during those minutes before and after I posted my answer

Comment: I also find it borderline offensive that you call quotes to the specification that *explain why the error was thrown* not relevant... they are absolutely relevant and I took time out of my day to find and interpret them, finally presenting them.

Comment: @AndrewLi I didn't said it's not relevant, I said it obfuscate the relevant parts, which a quote from the specification adds little to. But that's only my opinion.

Comment: My intention was to make the spec quotes *the main part of my answer*. It's completely relevant in my opinion as it explains why it's illegal - *which is the OP's question*. The other parts where I am accused of vampirism, I wanted to add for completeness. Sorry I did not give attribution at first but my answer is objectively different.

Comment: @AndrewLi it looks like it is now that you've been called out. But essentially, 2/3 of your answer, the part that help the asker understand, were word for word my answer and [_An elegant solution for “answer-stealing” edits?_](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21643/an-elegant-solution-for-answer-stealing-edits) explains well how to take every answer and make one better without "stealing".

Comment: Kind of OT but: Sometimes it's good to have 2 answers. A short and simple one for people to help immediately. And one with more in-depth information to read more about it. (concerning the part with quotes from specification etc)

Comment: @EmileBergeron From the start I told you I was sorry, and I was unaware of the correct course of action. I didn't change much after I was 'called out'. The only thing I did to that part was give attribution which I personally did not known should've been done. If you would have told me to do so, would've gladly done it yesterday.

Comment: @AndrewLi it's ok, I'm not the one who brought this here. I did upvote your answer in the end and never downvoted any of yours. At first, I just wanted to inform the asker of the behavior and let him make the call.

Comment: My problem with this is that you call my answer 'stealing' from yours. If I could, I would travel back in time and record what I did. My answer was posted less than 15 seconds after yours and had the same content. After that, someone else had added a solution so I did so too, which happened to be the same one. After that, I started searching in the spec to get a better understanding, in which he massive edit happened. I saw that the OP had trouble understanding the content of your answer so I added some into mine. No malice was intended, just me trying to help.

Comment: @AndrewLi it hasn't happened exactly in that order, it was multiple close edits, each time taken from my answer in the same order they were added, minutes or seconds after.

Comment: @EmileBergeron That's fine - just in the future if you feel like there has been injustice, please contact the person you have conflict with. I would have loved to have a mature discussion, and I posted here because I didn't want to engage in an unproductive immature discussion, seeking the input of the community in if it was really stealing

Comment: @AndrewLi I try to avoid pointless internet arguments, that's why I contacted the asker instead.

Comment: @EmileBergeron I try to too, but I would have gladly accepted. Regarding the edits, my original answer did not have the solution, that's all it lacked. I then edited to include a solution and explanation. Anyways, I hope I can set this behind us, and we can move on. No hard feelings from me :-)

Comment: @AndrewLi No hard feelings either, your answer is definitely more complete now and deserves the attention it received and will receive.

Comment: Why the downvotes here? It's quite interesting to read :P

Answer (score 11):

> I then did a gigantic edit which encompassed all their other edits

Why not refer instead to OP's answer: "As xxx mentions... In addition..."? I see this a lot in SO answers and it seems better form to me and less plagiaristic.

Comment: That's what I would have expected. And I wouldn't have made his addition into my answer, leaving both to coexist.